# Loading data from HDF5 to vector in C++

Tags: c++, hdf5

**Update**:  After looking at an h5dump, it turns out it's a compound data format.  My fault for using python to create the damn files I suppose!

snippit from h5dump:

```
DATASET "dset1" {
               DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
                  16-bit little-endian floating-point "value";
```

---

I've got a bunch of HDF5 files, which I can read and write in Matlab, but now I want to use C++.  After following examples, I'm still unable to crack it.

I don't think I'm understanding or implementing the memory types properly, judging by the error I'm getting at runtime.  How do you know which memory types to use?

Below is my code, and the error I get at runtime.  It fails at the dset.read line.  (I've tried various implementations/memory types here).

The dataset properties as reported by HDFView on a Windows 64bit machine are 32-bit floating-point.  The code is running on Mint 17 64bit.

Compiled using:

```
g++ importH5.cpp -o importH5 -std=c++11 -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5
```

ImportH5.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <H5Cpp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace H5;

int main()
{
    string ifn = "test.h5";
    string datasetPath = "/grp1/grp2/grp3/dset1";

    // Open HDF5 file handle, read only
    H5File fp(ifn.c_str(),H5F_ACC_RDONLY);

    // access the required dataset by path name
    DataSet dset = fp.openDataSet(datasetPath.c_str());

    // get the dataspace
    DataSpace dspace = dset.getSpace();

    // get the dataset type class
    H5T_class_t type_class = dset.getTypeClass();
    // According to HDFView, this is a 32-bit floating-point

    // get the size of the dataset
    hsize_t rank;
    hsize_t dims[2];
    rank = dspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims, NULL); // rank = 1
    cout<<"Datasize: "<<dims[0]<<endl; // this is the correct number of values

    // Define the memory dataspace
    hsize_t dimsm[1];
    dimsm[0] = dims[0];
    DataSpace memspace (1,dimsm);


    // create a vector the same size as the dataset
    vector<float> data;
    data.resize(dims[0]);
    cout<<"Vectsize: "<<data.size()<<endl;


    float data_out[65341];
    for (int i=0;i<65341;i++)
    {
        data_out[i]=0;
    }
    // pass pointer to the array (or vector) to read function, along with the data type and space.
    dset.read(data_out, PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace, dspace); // FAILS
    dset.read(data_out, PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, dspace);           // FAILS
    dset.read(data.data(), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace, dspace); // FAILS


    // close the HDF5 file
    fp.close();



return 0;
}
```

And the error:

```
Datasize: 65341
Vectsize: 65341
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.11) thread 139863993304960:
  #000: ../../../src/H5Dio.c line 182 in H5Dread(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #001: ../../../src/H5Dio.c line 438 in H5D__read(): unable to set up type info
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #002: ../../../src/H5Dio.c line 939 in H5D__typeinfo_init(): unable to convert between src and dest datatype
    major: Dataset
    minor: Feature is unsupported
  #003: ../../../src/H5T.c line 4525 in H5T_path_find(): no appropriate function for conversion path
    major: Datatype
    minor: Unable to initialize object
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'H5::DataSetIException'
Aborted
```

And here's a link to the HDF5 file, if it's of use: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63051/test.h5

Comment: After you call `rank = dspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims, NULL);`, what is the value of the `rank`?

Comment: Using cout<<rank I get a value of 1 (I'll update the question to clarify that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your issue is using python to create it. As it has you have mentioned it has put it into a compounded datatype.

You are almost there...

First you need to create a struct to hold the data. Lets call it `pyf` (unimaginative me - python float).

```
struct pyf {
        float x;
};
```

Then you need to change your `data_out` to be of this type.

```
struct pyf data_out[65341];
for (int i=0;i<65341;i++)
{
    data_out[i].x=0;
}
```

Finally you need to create a HDF5 compounded type and tell it what member you want from the file:

```
CompType mtype( sizeof(struct pyf) );
mtype.insertMember("value", HOFFSET(struct pyf, x), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
dset.read(data_out, mtype);
```

Lastly a sanity check:

```
for (int i=0;i<65341;i++)
{
    cout<<data_out[i].x << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Works a treat! I think I'm going to re-create the HDF5s with another method (C or C++) to avoid this though - no sense leaving a relic of complexity behind for future headaches!